# Active Merchant paypal recurring payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I am using Active Merchant gem to handle payments through the site. But now i want to make these payments recurring, on a monthly basis. Is there a way using active merchant or?

subscription_controller.rb

```
    class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @home_page = true
    @white = true
    @subscription = Subscription.new(token: params[:token])
    if !logged_in?
      redirect_to signup_url
    end
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    @subscription.remote_ip = request.remote_ip
    @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
    if @subscription.save
      if @subscription.purchase
        @subscription.send_thank_you_email
        redirect_to thankyou_path
      else
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        flash[:notice] = "It seems something went wrong with the paypal transaction. Please check that your credit card is valid and has credit in it and try again."
        redirect_to :back
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong with marking your purchase as complete. Please contact support to check it out."
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def purchase
    response = GATEWAY.setup_purchase(999,
      ip: request.remote_ip,
      return_url: new_subscription_url,
      cancel_return_url: root_url,
      currency: "USD",
      items: [{name: "Order", description: "Recurring payment for ******", quantity: "1", amount: 999}]
    )
    redirect_to GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
  end

  def thank_you
    @home_page = true
    @white = true
  end

  private

    def subscription_params
      params.require(:subscription).permit(:token)
    end


end
```

subscription.rb model

```
def purchase
    response = GATEWAY.purchase(999, express_purchase_options)
    response.success?
  end

  def token=(token)
    self[:token] = token
    if new_record? && !token.blank?
      # you can dump details var if you need more info from buyer
      details = GATEWAY.details_for(token)
      puts details.params["PayerInfo"]["PayerName"].inspect
      self.payer_id = details.payer_id
      self.first_name = details.params["PayerInfo"]["PayerName"]["FirstName"]
      self.last_name = details.params["PayerInfo"]["PayerName"]["LastName"]
    end
  end

  # send thank you email
  def send_thank_you_email
    UserMailer.thank_you(self).deliver_now
  end

  private

  def express_purchase_options
    {
      :ip => remote_ip,
      :token => token,
      :payer_id => payer_id
    }
  end
```

production.rb environment

```
config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production
    ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(
      :login => ENV['PAYPAL_LOGIN'],
      :password => ENV['PAYPAL_PASSWORD'],
      :signature => ENV['PAYPAL_SIGNATURE']
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ActiveMerchant used to have something like this:

```
    subscription = PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.recurring(@subscription.price_in_cents, nil, 
        :description => 'blah',
        :start_date => Date.tomorrow, 
        :period => 'Year',
        :frequency => 1,
        :amount => price,
        :currency => 'USD'
    )
```

See this answer [Does ActiveMerchant support Subscription Based transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154302/does-activemerchant-support-subscription-based-transaction)

Also see this: https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal_express.rb

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/paypal/paypal_recurring_api.rb

Comment: but how do i use it? where do i implement it in my case?

Comment: Seems you can create an action in one of your controllers, require ActiveMerchant, then build the request with your product information.

Comment: after research i think paypal recurring is deprecated. Thus i have now implemented the paypal_recurring gem which does the job nicely.

Comment: More on ActiveMerchant deprecation of recurring billing: https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/pull/1178